# App testing return "NullInjectorError: No provider for Location!"

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular7

Testing an app in Angular 7 with Karma, I can't remove the error in subj.

I have searched various places (mostly here) but either the solutions don't work or are not relevant to my case.

App.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Header.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.less']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    constructor(private location: Location, private router: Router) { 
        setInterval(() => {
            this.now = new Date();
        }, 1000);
    }
...
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.which === this.KEY_ESCAPE){
            if (this.router.url !== '/'){
                this.location.back();
            }
        }
    }
```

App.component.spec.ts:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        RouterOutlet
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

```
AppComponent should create the app
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HeaderComponent -> Location]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HeaderComponent -> Location]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Location!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it: all I needed to do was to import `RouterModule.forRoot([])`, which seems to be a common mistake as it fixes a lot of `StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)` errors.

Comment: Could extend your answer and explain which file needs this import?

Comment: To the spec file imports.

Answer (score 28):

In my case, I was using the RouterTestingModule already which should not raise this error. I have imported Location from the wrong place so the error has appeared. 'Location' should be imported from here:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
```

In your imports you should only import RouterTestingModule like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
          [
            {path: 'add', component: DummyComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
          ]
        )
      ],
```

and then you can use Location like this:

```
it('Should navigate to / before + button click', () => {
    const location: Location = TestBed.get(Location);
    expect(location.path()).toBe('');
  });
```

Just don't forget to import Location from @angular/common

Comment: Anyway, I always suggest using a spy on router navigation rather than using Location directly.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to `NullInjectorError: No provider for Location!` during the testing is to import `RouterTestingModule`.

ex. `mycomponent.spec.ts:`

```
    import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
    ...
    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ RouterTestingModule ]
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u try  to `import` > `CommonModule`

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [CommonModule]
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        RouterOutlet
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```