# Karma and Jasmine in Angular testing Error

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

these are the devDependencies of my JSON file I use Angular version 6

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"}
```

and my **menu.component.spec.ts** is

```typescript
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';
import { DishService } from '../services/dish.service';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';
import { baseURL } from '../shared/baseurl';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';


describe('MenuComponent', () => {
  
  let component: MenuComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MenuComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    const dishServiceStub = {
      getDishes: function(): Observable<Dish[]> {
        return of(DISHES);
      }
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent }])
        
      ],
      declarations: [ MenuComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: DishService, useValue: dishServiceStub },
        { provide: 'baseURL', useValue: baseURL }

      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    const dishservice = TestBed.get(DishService);

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  // it('dishes items should be 4', () => {
  //   expect(component.dishes.length).toBe(4);
  // }
  // );
});
```

and when I run the "ng test" command I get this error in the Karma Debugging tab

> MenuComponent should create
> Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[BaseURL]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BaseURL]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for BaseURL!
> Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[BaseURL]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BaseURL]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for BaseURL!
> at NullInjector.get (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1360:19)
> at resolveToken (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1598:24)
> at tryResolveToken (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1542:16)
> at StaticInjector.get (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1439:20)
> at resolveToken (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1598:24)
> at tryResolveToken (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1542:16)
> at StaticInjector.get (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1439:20)
> at resolveNgModuleDep (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:8667:29)
> at NgModuleRef_.get (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9355:16)
> at resolveDep (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9720:45)

Comment: The error says `NullInjectorError: No provider for BaseURL!` Might it be due to case, because I can see you have provided for `baseURL` and not `BaseURL`

Comment: Try using `RouterModule.forRoot([])`
It is the recommended solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56325514/app-testing-return-nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-location